# Sum of three independent variables with same uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I've seen the Irwin-Hall distribution which is for the sum of n independent variables with a standard uniform distribution.

However, is there a more general version that would help me find the distribution of `W = X + Y - Z` , where X, Y and Z are independent and are each uniformly distributed from `0` to `alpha`?

Many thanks for any tips.

Comment: In the title you speak of "sum of...same uniform distribution" but the distribution of $X,Y$ differs from the distribution of $-Z$. Did you mean to write $W=X+Y+Z$?

Comment: The density function of the sum of two independent real random variables is the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of the two density functions.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Indeed, the **-Z** has a different distribution. Is there any general approach for such uniform variable other than calculating the convolution? What if it was **+Z** instead?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $IH_3$ an Irwin–Hall distribution for the sum of $3$ independent and identically distributed $U(0, 1)$ random variables, so with support on $[0,3]$ with mean $\frac32$ and variance $\frac14$

- If you are looking at $X+Y+Z$ the sum of $3$ independent and identically distributed $U(0, \alpha)$ random variables, then this distribution would be a rescaling by $\alpha$ of $IH_3$, so with support on $[0,3\alpha]$ with mean $\frac32\alpha$ and variance $\frac14\alpha^2$
- Since $Z$ and $\alpha-Z$ have the same distribution and are each independent of $X$ and $Y$, if you were looking at $X+Y+(\alpha-Z)$, then this distribution would also be a rescaling by $\alpha$ of $IH_3$, so again with support on $[0,3\alpha]$ with mean $\frac32\alpha$ and variance $\frac14\alpha^2$
- If you are looking at $X+Y-Z$, then this distribution would be a rescaling by $\alpha$ of $IH_3$ then location-shifted by $-\alpha$, so with support on $[-\alpha,2\alpha]$ with mean $\frac12\alpha$ and variance $\frac14\alpha^2$